# PHP date formating in JS

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime

Im trying to figure out how to pass a date in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` through JS that I have done in PHP before, but PHP and JS being different in this sense. I am at a bit of a loss.

Heres how I did it in PHP:

```
var default_dob = strtotime(date('m/d/Y', time()) .' -18 year');
var dob = date('m/d/Y', default_dob);
```

essentially taking todays date, subtracting 18 years, and reformatting it so its `mm/dd/yyyy` for a date picker. Idealy I'd like to avoid adding in another plugin to my already big stack of JS. So if I can do this without the extra weight (outside of being able to plug it into maybe a ready made function Ill be happy)

Comment: Refer this Site [http://phpjs.org/functions/date/](http://phpjs.org/functions/date/)

Answer (score 1):

This will alert the date in your required format exactly 18 years back.

```
var date = new Date(); 
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 18); 
alert(date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Left pad a string to the specified length using the specified character
function padLeft(str, length, char)
{
    // Make sure args really are strings and that the length is a positive
    // number. If you don't do this concatenation may do numeric addition!
    str = String(str);
    char = String(char) || ' '; // default to space for pad string
    length = Math.abs(Number(length));
    if (isNaN(length)) {
        throw new Error("Pad length must be a number");
    }

    if (str.length < length) {
        // Prepend char until the string is long enough
        while (str.length < length) {
            str = char + str;
        }

        // Make sure the string is the requested length
        return str.slice(length * -1);
    } else {
        // The string is already long enough, return it
        return str;
    }
}

// Get the current date/time
// This is local to the browser, so it depends on the user's system time
var default_dob = new Date();

// Subtract 18 years
default_dob.setFullYear(default_dob.getFullYear() - 18);

// Format the string as you want it. PHP's d and m formats add leading zeros
// if necessary, in JS you have to do it manually.
var dob = padLeft(default_dob.getMonth(), 2, '0') + '/'
        + padLeft(default_dob.getDate(), 2, '0') + '/'
        + default_dob.getFullYear()
```

See also: [MDN entry on the `Date()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ss=  date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+18 year'));
?>
var default_dob = '<?php echo $ss;?>';
alert(default_dob);
</script>
```